# What type of variable is most appropriate for this task?

Tags: java, arrays, variables, types

I am currently creating a class for a small project and ran into an interesting scenario that I haven't really dealt with before.

My program will just display information about certain items in a game. The category I'm having issues with is the costs of the item. For instance, the item cost can be:

- 100 Silver and 300 Stone
- 500 Copper, 300 Stone, and 2 Rare Metal
- 175 Gold

The cost could be any of those, meaning it could only cost one type of 'currency' or could cost up to three different kinds of 'currency'. Also, each type of currency would contain a picture of it. So `100 Silver and 300 Stone` would look something like: `100(Int) Silver(image) and 300(Int) Stone(Image)`

So seeing as there could be multiple types of currency and images, would one store it in an array? Or another type of variable?

Just looking for someone to shed light on the issue. If it needs to be explained with a sample of the class, I can do so.

***EDIT***

Although my explanation lacked clarity, I received many good responses. In fact, quite a few are suitable to be the correct answer. I appreciate all the responses and have upvoted each of you who had helpful feedback.

Thank you everyone!!!

Comment: So in the game, the currency consists of the four following units: gold, silver, copper, stone, rare metal, and any given item could be any combination of these four?

Comment: It has more than four units but I decided to pick four at random to explain to point. If I had to guess there are about twelve different units. I'm wanting to make the units appear as pictures and the values appear as Integer (Changed from String because I realized that I will actually do calculations with the numbers)

Comment: Yes, an example would be: A long sword costs 200 Metal. Where as an Ax costs 200 Gold and 2 Metal. Does that clear it up a bit?

Comment: So each item should be able to store as many different currency units as needed to represent its cost, theoretically up to 12 different units or possibly even more?

Comment: That is correct :) I think when I get the chance I'll add an image and a better explanation for others if it isn't resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a very simple class Cost

```
public class Cost {
    int amount;
    String currency;

    public Cost(int amount, String currency) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

and then implement the cost as an ArrayList

```
List<Cost> cost = new ArrayList<Cost>();
cost.add (new Cost(100, "Gold"));
```

This is simple enough while retaining flexibility to add new currencies

---

### An example with an enum:

```
public class Cost {
    private int amount;
    private Currency currency;

    public Cost(int amount, Currency currency) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public enum Currency {
        GOLD { public String toString() { return "gold"; } },
        SILVER { public String toString() { return "silver"; } },
        COPPER { public String toString() { return "copper"; } },
        STONE { public String toString() { return "stone"; } },
        RARE_METAL { public String toString() { return "rare"; } }
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return new String(currency.toString()+".png");
    }

    public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency.toString();
    }
}
```

---

```
List<Cost> costs = new ArrayList<Cost>();
cost.add (new Cost(100, Cost.Currency.GOLD));
cost.add (new Cost(200, Cost.Currency.COPPER));

for (Cost cost: costs) {
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon(cost(i).getImageName());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel(cost(i).getAmount(), icon, JLabel.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: I had considered doing something of the sort, but wondered how to handle the image for the unit. In the Gui would it be efficient to grab the image path based on the string gold?

Comment: Yes, why not? The class I wrote is too basic to be useful, but it shows the idea. You will need getters and setters to avoid keeping public fields in it. You can add a getImage() method that will return the path based on the string. I would not keep an image in each object because that would be extremely costly

Comment: Another point is to determine how flexible you want the currency field to be: a String will allow you to add any currency (useful or not), while an Enum may help to limit it to the available currencies.

Comment: Thank you for the great advice! I really like how simple the class can be in this example.

Comment: @StartingGroovy I added the enum idea I told you in the comment above

Comment: @Aleadam thank you for posting that, can you briefly explain how I would display this on my Gui? Would I be able to display both the text and the image in a jLabel?

Comment: @StartingGroovy This new update should get you started. I improved a little bit the class and added a JLabel example.

Comment: One last comment: you may also want to extend ArrayList to add some verification methods (for example, that you cannot add twice a GOLD cost).

Comment: Thank you Aleadam for all the help, it's quite appreciated.

Comment: @Aleadam Is your enhanced loop suitable for an object that only has one jLabel available? (Or would one need to put in extras in case?) I'm not too familiar with enhanced for loops, but wouldn't your control variable have to be declared somewhere? (I know it's just an example, but I'm just curious about it as its something new to me)

Answer (score 2):

Java's an object-oriented language; why not have an Item or Commodity class that encapsulates the behavior that you want instead of relying on primitives?  You'll hide complexity from clients by encapsulating it into the class.

If you have several Currency instances, you can also encapsulate conversions between them rather than embed constants all over your code.  If you change conversions, you'll only have to do it in one place.

Comment: Good point, I guess I was slightly confused since there could be multiple costs rather than just one. If I'm not mistaken, you're suggesting something similar to what Aleadam has posted?

Answer (score 2):

Also, and this is important so I'm putting it at the top, even though it's an edit.
**Don't include pictures in anything with this** You should only have pictures on the user interface. In theory, you could run the game from a command prompt just typing your commands. "Buy sword" "sell junk" "attack goblin" etc. When you start incorporating your UI and "business logic" you find yourself having a very difficult time separating the two when it comes time to fix stuff.

I would have something like this

```
class Cost {
    // use the builder pattern - it makes it VERY easy to add new currency types
    // without breaking existing types
    // it does make it more difficult to remove types, but you would have to
    // modify everywhere a type that used a removed currency anyway, so it's no
    // ADDITIONAL work there.
    class Builder {
        private int copper;
        private int silver;
        private int gold;

        public Builder copper(int cu) { this.copper = cu; return this; }
        public Builder silver(int ag) { this.silver = ag; return this; }
        public Builder gold(int au) { this.gold = au; return this; }

        public Cost complete() {
            return new Cost(this);
        }

    }
    public final int copper;
    public final int silver;
    public final int gold;
    // other costs;

    private Cost(CostBuilder cb) {
        this.copper = cb.copper;
        this.silver = cb.silver;
        this.gold = cb.gold;
    }

}

class Item {
    String name;
    // other stuff

    private Set<Cost> costs;

    public Set<Cost> getCosts() {
        return java.util.Collections.unmodifiableSet(costs);
    }
}
```

use the code like this:

```
Cost allGold = new Cost.Builder().gold(175).complete();
Cost goldAndSilver = new Cost.Builder().silver(50).gold(50).complete();
Cost allMaterials = new Cost.Builder().gold(10).silver(30).copper(100).complete();

Set<Cost> costs = new HashSet<Cost>();
costs.add(allGold);
costs.add(goldAndsilver);
costs.add(allMaterials);

Item swordOf1000Truths = new Item("Sword of 1000 truths",costs);
```

and later you can do this

```
// assume player found allGold by quering for what costs he could use
if(player.canAfford(allGold)) {
    player.spend(allGold);
    player.addItem(swordOf1000Truths);
}
```

Comment: I like the code, it covers all the necessary fields. Thank you for the example

Comment: @glowcoder When I get to the user interface, how would I get access to the necessary information to know what images to place up? Would I use a getter on the cost?

Comment: @StartingGroovy actually in this case, because I made the variables `public final`, you don't need to use a getter. You can simply go `allGold.gold`. And yes, you would have a check for each type and display it if the type is not 0.

Comment: @glowcoder your answer was great and I appreciate it. Thank you for your time

Comment: @StartingGroovy not a problem. I would like to point out that your selected answer uses some excellent design patterns. Study that intently as well. I would also like to point out that our answers are not mutually exclusive. If, for example, you were to rename his to `CostElement`, you could reimplement my `Cost` class with a `Set<CostElement>` and use the builder pattern quite effectively to create an immutable, maintainable item-cost system. I'm not kidding when I say I will be revisiting this exact page when it comes time for me to implement item costs in my own game. :-)

Comment: @glowcoder Thats quite interesting, thank you for pointing that out. I will be tinkering with all code samples posted in here and get a good understanding of them before I proceed.

Answer (score 1):

In the code I would just store the cost of the item as a single value (int or double).  Then when you display the cost have some class that translates the internal value into whatever currency you want to show.

No need to carry around an array of values if all the values are essentially the same.

Comment: I believe I did a poor job of explaining it in my original post. How would I store 100 Silver and 300 Stone as an Int or Double? I'm wanting to break it down into parts: `100 Silver, 300 Stone` which could further be broken down into `100 (Int), Silver (Image), 300 (Int), Stone (Image)` If necessary I can add an image to make it more understandable as I feel the way I have worded it, is confusing in itself

Comment: You store it as whatever internal value 100 silver and 300 stone translates into.  For example, you don't store $3.95 as 3 dollars and 95 cents, you store it as a double of value 3.95.  Or, say you just stored everything as pennies.  Then you could store $3.95 as the value 395.  Then you could translate that into dollars and cents, or pennies, nickels, dimes, or nickels and quarters, etc...  It's the same idea, just replace nickels with stone, etc...  It will also be a lot easier to do all the addition/subtraction that way.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! While I don't think I can change everything into one standard in this case, I will have to do so with some of the methods I create in the class. Thanks dgundersen!

Comment: Let's say 1 gold == 1000 silver, 1 silver == 1000 copper, 1 copper == 1000 stone (for simplicity's sake).  Then you can store all values as the cost in stones, and 1002003004 can be considered as 1 gold, 2 silver, 3 copper, 4 stone.  This depends on the monetary units having a fixed relationship with each other (ie: "1 gold == 1000 silver"), but they don't all have to be equally spaced out.

Comment: @cHao Correct, but in the game I'm working with, the monetary units can fluctuate every few hours which is why I think this approach might be rather difficult.

Answer (score 1):

No built in type of variable is appropriate, so you need to make Classes that represent your concepts. At least Cost should be a class and maybe also currency, but an Enum might do for that.

Comment: Thank you, you and a few others have pointed this out. It looks like I'll have to break down a few other things into classes as well. In the end it would simplify a few things and keep the code clean

Comment: @StartingGroovy I think you'll be surprised by much the rest of your code will be simplified and improved by getting your model classes right.

Comment: I too think I will be surprised. I seem to struggle on how to separate my code into classes. I'm hoping to improve on it a bit

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go for an enum to represent the various types of currencies.  Something like this:

```
public enum Currency {
    GOLD("gold"),
    SILVER("silver"),
    COPPER("copper"),
    STONE("stone");

    private String displayName;

    private Currency(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return displayName;
    }
}
```

Here the enum actually has a field to store a user-friendly display name for the currency; this isn't necessary--I just threw it in to make the output pretty later on in my example.  It could also store a corresponding image filename (or even an actual image) but that might be better left up to whatever UI you're using rather than putting it in the model here.

Your item needs just one `Map` to store its costs:

```
private Map<Currency, Integer> costs;
```

A rough example of how to use it:

```
Item vorpalSword = new Item();
vorpalSword.getCosts().put(Currency.GOLD, 100);
vorpalSword.getCosts().put(Currency.STONE, 300);

StringBuilder costOutput = new StringBuilder();
for(Map.Entry<Currency, Integer> cost : vorpalSword.getCosts().entrySet()) {
    costOutput.append(cost.getValue() + " " + cost.getKey() + " ");
}
System.out.println(costOutput.toString());
```

Comment: Very well put, thank you Jeff. I also like this example. I have quite a few to choose from now :) +1

Comment: Thank you Jeff for your time and the answer, I like how you made use of Map.